# How can I pull a credit report on my 20-year-old son?

Tags: united-states, credit, credit-report

My wife and I would like to see a credit report on our 20-year-old son. He is a college student, and we are responsible for virtually all of his expenses. We want to ensure he doesn't have credit/debt that we don't know about.

Is this possible without his knowledge or permission?

Comment: It may be possible, but I think what you should be more concerned about is whether it is **legal**.

Comment: Why can't you just ask him for his permission to obtain his credit report?

Comment: The number one thing teens like is trust from there parents.  Ask him / her if you can obtain the credit report and have him / her provide you one.  Going around there back and getting their credit report at that age is not so nice.

Comment: Can you, yes. As a parent you probably have all of the relevant information just like a spouse might spy on their significant other without permission. Is it legal, no.

Comment: I wish some of these comments were answers so I could upvote them... (hint hint)

Comment: `We want to ensure he doesn't have credit/debt that we don't know about.` Why?

Comment: How can your son pull a credit report on you?

Comment: “We want to ensure he doesn't have credit/debt that we don't know about.” — Unless you know of an omniscient credit agency, you can’t. He can, in theory, borrow money from anyone in the world.

Comment: And — “Is this possible without his knowledge or permission?” Not if he sees this page!

Comment: My dad has attempted something similar. He took a second or two to long to answer one of the questions and they locked my entire account down. I had to phone the company to get it up and running again. They said it was indeed fraud even though it was my dad.

Also you shouldnt go behind your sons back.

Comment: This is a question about trust, not finance. The question doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Can you pull a credit report on your adult child, spouse - or even any other adult for that matter? If you have access to things like national ID (Social Security number), can answer security questions related to addresses they have previously lived and outstanding major debts they may have (house loans, car loans, etc), then sure you **physically can**.

Now, ***is it legal to do so***? [According to Experian](http://www.experian.com/ask-experian/20060405-when-an-ex-spouse-attempts-to-get-your-credit-report.html) (a credit bureau) obtaining someone's credit report without their permission is considered identity theft and fraud, *even if you do not use it for some nefarious purpose.* **Even if you are a parent,** it is a violation of federal and state laws and is punishable by fines and imprisonment.

**Can they find out?** Absolutely! [Answering a question wrong](http://www.whatsmyscore.org/getscore/faq.php) (according to Visa), or in some other way tripping a security alert (such as if the person has intentionally put a "freeze" on their account and opted-in to some identity theft protection scheme, [such as one requiring a special pin](https://www.experian.com/freeze/center.html)), will cause your attempt to fail and often require calling the company directly to provide additional verification information (which of course you may not have and is less predictable). Depending on the [monitoring scheme](http://www.money-zine.com/financial-planning/debt-consolidation/credit-report-monitoring/), a monitoring service might even send an email or letter to a person directly if such an attempt is made (but this does vary by service and bureau).

Even if you do it correctly, all requests are logged and often are noted on credit reports regarding past inquiries - so if in the future they run their credit report they may see the inquiry they will know they didn't request (that's weird, this is the first time I've ever checked my credit...). If the person is using a mailing address you don't know about, like a PO Box or a friend's house to get mail (so you don't know about their card/statements/loans), then you will almost certainly lock the account and a fraud alert will be sent in a way you can't intercept. That's going to be an unpleasant set of conversations!

**The alternative:** [As Mint.com suggests, just get their permission!](https://www.mint.com/blog/credit/how-can-i-get-a-copy-of-someone-elses-credit-report-122011/) You can request it so you can go over the importance of good credit with them, or you can tell them outright you are concerned that they may be getting themselves into debt. You can bribe them with getting them a for-fee credit score and analysis at your expense, or extort them by demanding that if they don't like it they can live somewhere else...how you play it is up to you.

But horror stories are easily avoided, and you can use the opportunity to actually get a credit report and sit down and go over it together. Do they know what a report is and what's on it? Most adults twice their age sure don't!

**Parenting tip bonus**: if you are open and honest and explain why you'd like to get a credit report and sit down with them to discuss it and they freak out - bingo, you've got an answer that something is wrong and it didn't cost you a dime and you didn't break the law.

Now, ***to be completely clear***, if they don't respond well to the credit report that isn't evidence of some kind of guilt or impropriety (a thanks to the comments for pointing out this potential misinterpretation). However, what it **does** indicate is your relationship may be out of whack - imbalanced or unhealthy in some way. You could be in a co-dependent situation where you are covering for them so they don't have to be responsible or independent (bad for both of you), or they may be hiding from reality, or you may have have developed serious trust and boundary issues that need to be addressed, or any of dozens of other possibilities!

All of  these are possible - they might be really screwing up, or maybe you are, or maybe you both are, or maybe it's all ok and you can relax. I hope this makes clear the importance of figuring out what reality is and dealing with that, which is the foundation of personal financial health and healthy personal relationships, too!

Comment: The last tip works even with your boyfriend/girlfriend/husband/wife/friend/relative. It isn't just a good parenting tip: this is a life lesson! If someone is asked about something 'sensitive' and they get all defensive, something is wrong! This is the way I would proceed!

Comment: or maybe they just don't want to share the personal detail of their life. Even spouses can have secrets from each other. I'd be uncomfortable sharing financial details with my parents even though there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Femaref : But I doubt you'd react in the same way if there were something to worry about. Your concerned-other should know you well enough to know the difference in the two reactions. That is all BrianDHall is saying.

Comment: I would totally freak out if my parents would ask me about this, even though there is nothing there. It is absolutely not my parents business, just like it is not my business to inquire their credit reports.

Comment: @eis the OP states they are supporting their son and paying expenses. Presumably they feel that any debts he runs up will be theirs to pay as well. This makes for a slightly different situation than pure nosiness and "none of their business"

Comment: @KateGregory I agree - I was just provoked by the comment by Ismael Miguel about this being a life lesson. It may be suitable and even ok in some situations, but I'd definitely not recommend it to be a guideline to live by.

Comment: Bonus Bonus Parenting Tip: Offer to go through the process with them so that *they* learn the importance of and process of getting their own credit score.

Comment: And now we transfer this to parenting.stackexchange, right?

Comment: If you enquire about something sensitive and someone reacts incredulously, it might just be because they're upset that you've just demonstrated that you don't trust them... and you've further demonstrated that you don't respect their privacy. So, yes, it does indicate that something is wrong, but not necessarily with them.

Comment: As a thank you to all the comments, I've updated my answer to clear up confusion about someone objecting to personal details. Please let me know if this doesn't address the stated issues, as I don't want to suggest someone wanting privacy or objecting to a trust issue is proof of guilt - and I also adjusted to point out that you, as the parent, can be the one in the wrong too. Hopefully I have done this without making it necessary to change it to a different stack exchange ;)

Comment: @Femaref As above, I adjusted me answer to take into account your concern, as I do agree. But if spouses or dependent (even if adult) children don't want to be financially open with one another, that's a relationship health problem and it's the foundation for financial problems - especially when one person's credit and finances are tied to another person's.

Comment: I also realized I didn't answer the "can you get caught" question, and I think frankly this is important so I added that too to fully answer the OP question.

Comment: @BrianDHall Can you either expand or source that most recent change?  The way you explained it I don't know that I agree with (though I'm not an expert so I'm happy to be proven wrong).  Is it really that easy to get caught?  If I start pulling my credit report then my child trips over a toy, am I going to get my credit report locked?

Comment: @Joe Good point, I'm going to add source and also soften it - security is both not that good and also less predictable, it seems.

Comment: @Joe There we go, I hope that section on getting caught is more clear now.

Comment: @Femaref `"even spouses"` is financial privacy actually an aberration between married couples?

Comment: @CQM This may vary by culture, but the general norm is spouses should be utterly open and united in their finances, with many experts suggesting you sit down and go over your credit report and all your finances before you even get married (and regularly after that, too). So people may not be privy to each other's every dollar (though many couples do this and it can be recommended by some experts), but married people who wouldn't share their credit report with each other is considered an aberration and a red flag. Keeping secret credit cards, loans, accounts, etc, is considered a big issue.

Comment: @BrianDHall I could imagine borrowing being an issue but I imagine scenarios where both are financially independent or successful, or where one is the breadwinner while the other is kept. I could see where both were working toward something (joint financial independence or child's education) that there would need to be a lot of trust. But in all my scenarios its more case by case than an absolute

Answer (score 6):

"{son's name} - it's important that you check your credit report to make sure there are no fradulent credit lines opened in your name, like someone using your identity for credit cards.  You can check it for free once every year from each of the three agencies - let's sit down and check yours this weekend, so you can see what it's like to pull the report and what information is on it."